# Metrics plugin Eclipse doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, plugins, metrics

I installed Metrics plugin in Eclipse Mars, but when I go to ther metrics view, it shows this message:

```
No metrics available for selection. To calculate and display metrics:

1) ensure you are in a java perspective using the package explorer
2) select a project and enable the metrics from its context menu
3) perform a full rebuild on the project

After the above steps, selecting any java element in the project will result in metrics being shown here. Automatic builds will keep the metrics up-to-date by re-calculating the metrics for changed elements only.
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin, but nothing, the problem is the same. By the way, I not have the possibility to enable metrics right-clicking on the projects, and I find the metrix box even if I click on properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question and this might not work for everyone, but simply changing the code and then executing it worked.

Doing stuff like rebuilding won't help as the plugin seems to detect that no changes have been made.

As I said, probably won't solve the problem for everyone but this would have saved me some time.